# Insert into table errors on "Invalid object name"

Tags: sql, sql-server

When this stored procedure executes, every instance of [dbo].[Synonym_Table1Unit] is recognized and the statements execute properly.  Except for the reference in the "Insert Into" statement at the end.  When that executes, I get:

> Invalid object name [dbo].[Synonym_Table1Unit]

```
USE [MyDatabase] 

IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
           FROM   sys.objects 
           WHERE  [name] = N'ValidatePallet' 
                  AND [type] = 'TR') 
  BEGIN 
      DROP TRIGGER [dbo].[ValidatePallet]; 
  END; 

go 

CREATE TRIGGER validatepallet 
ON table1unit 
instead OF INSERT 
AS 
  BEGIN 
      SET nocount ON 

      -- validate pallet character length of 3 
      IF EXISTS (SELECT oid 
                 FROM   inserted 
                 WHERE  Len(shippingboxcode) <> 17) 
        THROW 50000, '*** Pallet ID not 17 characters ***', 1 

      --  If length is OK, then test to see if this is the first unit record for this transaction.  If it is, no further validation.  If matches existing
      --  record, must then perform further validation 
      IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT i.oid 
                     FROM   inserted i 
                            JOIN [dbo].[synonym_table1unit] u 
                              ON i.table1oid = u.table1oid) 
        GOTO insertit 
      -->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>   No further validation required since this is the first unit for the transaction and length = 3
      ELSE 
      --  Match Validation > validation to ensure 1st 15 characters of Pallet ID always matches 
      IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT i.oid 
                     FROM   inserted i 
                            JOIN [dbo].[synonym_table1unit] u 
                              ON i.table1oid = u.table1oid 
                     WHERE  Substring(i.shippingboxcode, 1, 15) = 
                            Substring(u.shippingboxcode, 1, 15)) 
        THROW 50002, '*** Pallet ID not matching ***', 1 

      --  Validation to ensure no duplicate pallet 
      IF EXISTS (SELECT i.oid 
                 FROM   inserted i 
                        JOIN [dbo].[synonym_table1unit] u 
                          ON i.table1oid = u.table1oid 
                 WHERE  i.shippingboxcode = u.shippingboxcode) 
        THROW 50004, '*** Duplicate Pallet ID ***', 1 

      --Validation Passed  
      INSERTIT: 

      BEGIN 
          INSERT INTO [dbo].[synonym_table1unit] 
          SELECT * 
          FROM   inserted 
      END 
  -- This is END for the INSERT statement      
  END
```

Comment: you want to insert into all columns? Its most likely the columns dont exactly match. Also is it capital T or not [dbo].[Synonym_Table1Unit]

Comment: Hi Brien, thanks for cleaning that code up.  It looks much nicer.  But the suggestions don't solve it.  I have tested the insert statement in another context and it works fine.  The issue is that SQL doesn't like the Table Name for some reason, even though the same table name did not fail on the joins.

The capitalization is correct.